# Why does explorer's window opens in the background when supplying the /select, flag?

Tags: windows, windows-explorer

I want to open an explorer window with a file selected from command line (actually from Python, but let's take the command line for simplicity), and I want the window to get the focus and be in the front.

When I run `explorer C:\`, the explorer window opens in the front. When I run `explorer /select, C:\file.txt` however, it opens in the background, with the explorer icon blinking orange in the task bar.

Is it possible to open explorer in the front also with the /select, flag?